# `$().clone(true)` breaks event handlers in chrome extension (works on jsbin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, event-handling, clone

I am working on a chrome extension that can potentially mutate thousands of DOM elements. For performance reasons, I want to do this in memory rather than repeatedly touching the DOM. [jQuery's `clone`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) works great for this, as you can see in the following snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#click-me").on("click", () => {
    $("#click-count").html((idx, num) => ++num)
  })

  $("#with-cloning").click(function() {
    withCloning(($elem) => {
      $elem.find("h1").text("changed with cloning (still works)")
    })
  })

  $("#without-cloning").click(function() {
    withoutCloning(($elem) => {
      $elem.find("h1").text("changed without cloning (still works)")
    })
  })
})

function withCloning(mutateDom) {
  var $elem = $("body")
  // The `true` arg keeps bindings
  var $cloned = $elem.clone(true)
  mutateDom($cloned)
  $elem.replaceWith($cloned)
}

function withoutCloning(mutateDom) {
  mutateDom($("body"))
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <h1 id="click-me">Click me!</h1>
    <p>Click count: <span id="click-count">0</span></p>
  </div>
  
  <button id="without-cloning">replace without cloning</button>
  <button id="with-cloning">replace with cloning</button>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I use this exact same function in my chrome extension, it successfully replaces the contents, but **breaks all event handlers**.

The following function works perfectly both when embedded in a site (and in the snippet) **and** in my chrome extension:

```
function withoutCloning(mutateDom) {
  mutateDom($("body"))
}
```

How can I make the `withCloning` function behave correctly (as it does in the snippet) in a chrome extension?

---

### Additional Notes

- The [jQuery clone docs](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) describe the optional argument to `clone` thusly:

  > A Boolean indicating whether event handlers should be copied along with the elements. As of jQuery 1.4, element data will be copied as well.
- I'm not in any way attached to using jQuery's `clone`, if something else would be more appropriate (perhaps a document fragment).
- I've verified that the conflict is not with the `mutateDom` function by passing in `$elem => $elem`. The problem persists.

Comment: Please move/copy your code from JS Bin into a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: @Makyen Thanks for the tip, I'll be sure to do that in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is *expected* to break event handlers. You *can't* clone the event handlers, except events added by jQuery methods, using jQuery methods to clone or replace. Thus, replacing the contents of the DOM with a cloned copy will result in removing event handlers.

### jQuery `.clone()` can not clone non-jQuery events

jQuery has no way to know what events are on the elements when the event listeners were not added through jQuery methods. Thus, any events which were added through normal DOM methods (i.e. `.addEventListener()`) will not be cloned by jQuery's `.clone()`.

Here is an example which adds the count event handler using `addEventListener()`. You can see that the jQuery `.clone()` does not clone it, but does clone jQuery events (also [available on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/voqizuteni/1/edit?html,js,output)):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.querySelector("#click-me").addEventListener("click", () => {
    $("#click-count").html((idx, num) => ++num)
  })

  $("#with-cloning").click(function() {
    withCloning(($elem) => {
      $elem.find("h1").text("changed with cloning (counting does not work)")
    })
  })

  $("#without-cloning").click(function() {
    withoutCloning(($elem) => {
      $elem.find("h1").text("changed without cloning (still works)")
    })
  })
})

function withCloning(mutateDom) {
  var $elem = $("body")
  // The `true` arg keeps bindings
  var $cloned = $elem.clone(true)
  mutateDom($cloned)
  $elem.replaceWith($cloned)
}

function withoutCloning(mutateDom) {
  mutateDom($("body"))
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <h1 id="click-me">Click me!</h1>
    <p>Click count: <span id="click-count">0</span></p>
  </div>
  
  <button id="without-cloning">replace without cloning</button>
  <button id="with-cloning">replace with cloning</button>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

### jQuery can clone events added by jQuery methods

The reason that this is working in your JS Bin, is that you added all of your event handlers using jQuery. JQuery, effectively, keeps a record of the event handlers which you have added *through jQuery* and is able to clone the jQuery-added-events along with the elements when you `.clone()` the element, or use `.replaceWith()` to replace the element. This restoration of jQuery's event handlers occurs in *both* [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) and [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/). In other words, even if perform one of the two operations with the normal JavaScript methods ([`node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) or [`Node.replaceChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild)), but the other with jQuery's method (`.clone()` and `.replaceWith()`), jQuery will restore the events which you added using jQuery. You can use the following snippet to play around with which combinations of jQuery vs vanilla JavaScript which are used for the clone and to replace the element ([also on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/naloboviwo/1/edit?html,js,output)):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#click-me").on("click", () => {
    $("#click-count").html((idx, num) => ++num);
  });

  $("#with-cloning").click(function() {
    withCloning(($elem) => {
      $elem.find("h1").text("changed with cloning (still works)");
    });
  });

  $("#without-cloning").click(function() {
    withoutCloning(($elem) => {
      $elem.find("h1").text("changed without cloning (still works)");
    });
  });
});

function withCloning(mutateDom) {
  var $elem = $("body")
  var used='Used:';
  var $cloned;
  if($('#useClone').is(':checked')){
    //jQuery clone. The `true` arg keeps bindings
    $cloned = $elem.clone(true);
    used += ' clone()';
  } else {
    //Vanilla JavaScript cloneNode. `true` makes a deep copy
    $cloned = $($elem[0].cloneNode(true));
    used += ' cloneNode()';
  }
  mutateDom($cloned);
  if($('#useReplaceWith').is(':checked')){
    //jQuery replaceWith
    $elem.replaceWith($cloned);
    used += ' and replaceWith()';
  } else {
    //Vanilla JavaScript replaceChild
    $elem[0].parentNode.replaceChild($cloned[0],$elem[0]);
    used += ' and replaceChild()';
  }
  console.log(used);
}

function withoutCloning(mutateDom) {
  mutateDom($("body"));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <h1 id="click-me">Click me!</h1>
    <p>Click count: <span id="click-count">0</span></p>
  </div>
  
  <button id="without-cloning">replace without cloning</button>
  <button id="with-cloning">replace with cloning</button></br></br>
  Use:</br>
  <table>
    <tr><td>jQuery</td><td>vanilla JavaScript</td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="cloneType" type="radio" id="useClone" checked="true">`.clone(true)`</input></td>
      <td><input name="cloneType" type="radio" id="useCloneNode">`.cloneNode(true)`</input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="replaceType" type="radio" id="useReplaceWith" checked="true">`.replaceWith()`</input></td>
      <td><input name="replaceType" type="radio" id="usereplaceChild">`.replaceChild()`</input></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Note that once you have cloned with `.cloneNode()`, if you try to then again clone using `.clone(true)`, the events are not cloned.

Comment: Thanks, your second snippet made it very easy to see the problem I'm facing. I take it I'm just hosed and need to re-jigger the requirements?

Comment: @HenryBaughman, Basically, yes. As you've seen, jQuery's `.clone(true)` can not be used as a general purpose way to clone while including all events. Unfortunately, there is no interface that permits determining the events which have already been added. A possible alternative would be to clone the content, swap in the cloned content into the page, while retaining a reference to the current content. Then, mutate the content (you will still destroy any event listeners on elements *actually* replaced), and then swap in the original, now mutated content. Don't know, haven't tried that methodology.

Comment: @HenryBaughman, However, you should really look at performing the "mutation" in the active DOM. Browsers are smart. Unless you do something that requires the page to be re-evaluated, or use asynchronous methods, then the actual display of the page should not update until all of the changes you make are done (i.e. you end your current processing, or otherwise stop execution (e.g. call an async method and wait for the callback)). If you do need to do something async in order to get information for the update, just do all of it prior to beginning to do your mutation, then do all updates at once.

Comment: @HenryBaughman, Another method would be to insert a content script at `document_start` and keep a record of all events which were added by overriding the `.addEventListener()` and `removeEventListener()` methods. However, doing so may introduce a significant load on pages on which your extension is not actively being used. I can't estimate the impact due to not knowing enough about what your extension is trying to do and how it would be used.

Comment: The feature adds `ctrl+f` like behavior but with support for regex. I'm currently using [findAndReplaceDOMText](https://github.com/padolsey/findAndReplaceDOMText) which let you highlight across node boundaries. Long queries are less painful, and I *do* debounce input, but it's totally possible for a user to search `t` which will cause every `t` to be split out in a separate text node and wrapped in a span. For a 7000 word page that takes ~300ms vs ~6 seconds with and without cloning respectively. I'm thinking my best option is to only highlight the *current* match (e.g., "3 of 10").

Comment: You wrote "display of the page should not update until all of the changes you make are done". Reevaluation is definitely necessary, but "until all of the changes you make are done" implies to me that some sort of batching might be possible. Am I reading your correctly? I'm looking at [fastdom](https://github.com/wilsonpage/fastdom) and [dom-q](https://github.com/jaz303/dom-q), but was wondering if you had any suggestions for resources or libs. Thanks!